# Visual Studio Code Python не видит файлы

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mac

Пример моего кода:

```py
import csv

file_name = 'sitka_weather_2018_simple.csv'
with open(file_name) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    print(header_row)
```

Файл sitka_weather_2018_simple.csv находится в той же папке.
При запуске кода в Visual Studio Code выводится ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ivanlebedev/Documents/Python/csv_json/highs_lows.py", line 4, in <module>
    with open(file_name) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sitka_weather_2018_simple.csv'
```

При запуске из терминала все работает:

```
MacBook-Air-Ivan:csv_json ivanlebedev$ python3 highs_lows.py
['STATION', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'PRCP', 'TAVG', 'TMAX', 'TMIN']
```

Данная ошибка выскакивает так же с другими типами файлов, например с картинками. Помогите разобраться с проблемой.

Comment: Посмотрите може у файла `sitka_weather_2018_simple.csv` стоит атрибут "Только чтение" ?  и может попробуйте запустить VSC от имени администратора ?

Comment: windows? linux? mac?

Comment: по  моему это очевидно — Mac:
>>MacBook-Air-Ivan:csv_json ivanlebedev$ python3 highs_lows.py

Comment: Посмотрите в настройках VSC какая папка являетс рабочей для проекта и измените на ту, где лежит скрипт.

Comment: у меня mac, в свойствах стоит чтение и запись, скрит лежит в той же папке что и .csv файл